# Selenium : Add multiple path with send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, file-upload

When I try to add multiple path to an input type=file, one per one, it adds the file 1 then the file 1 and 2 etc...

```py
new_images = modify_images(ad['images_url'])
time.sleep(4)
add_images = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, image_add_xpath)
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(len(new_images)):
    print("image " + str(index) + " " + new_images[i])
    time.sleep(3)
    url = r"C:\\Users\\33651\Documents\Documents\\facebook-automate\\facebook-automate\\"+new_images[i]
    print(url)
    print("uploading")
    add_images.send_keys(url)
    print("Image uploadé")
    time.sleep(2)
```

I already tried to execute only one `send_keys` with the concatenation of the multiple path with the " \n " separator. It doesn't work.
I also tried to clear the input but It doesn't work neither.

```py
add_images = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, image_add_xpath)
        time.sleep(2)
        all_path_images = ""
        for i in range(len(new_images)):
            all_path_images += new_images[i] + ' \n '
            
        add_images.send_keys(all_path_images)
        print("Image uploadé")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the question, as well as show where `add_images` comes from. From your question it is not clear to me what you want to concatenate, and how that is related to your send keys not working.

Comment: I don't have any error, for example if len(new_images) = 3 then it will upload :
6 files (3 times the file 1, 2 times the files 2, 1 times the file 3) where I would it to upload only the 3 files.
I just put the code of the concatenate way above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code trials shown here looks like you didn't add the new line correctly.
To upload multiple files you can construct a string adding all the absolute paths of the uploaded files separated by \n , as following:

```py
all_path_images = ""
for i in range(len(new_images)):
    all_path_images + = r"C:\\Users\\33651\Documents\Documents\\facebook-automate\\facebook-automate\\" + new_images[i] + ' \n '
#remove the last new line character from the string
all_path_images = all_path_images.strip()
add_images.send_keys(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I already tried this and this returned me an error :
 Message: invalid argument: File not found
But without the ' \n ' , I don't have any error but it's the same problem about uploading too many files

Comment: You are right! I'm sorry. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried this?